# Cinnamon not detecting nvidia package drivers arch

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, cinnamon, lightdm, lightdm-gtk-greeter

I have just come from Ubuntu so getting used to Arch at the moment.

I have installed the cinnamon DE and lightdm. However whenever I boot into cinnamon I get a dialog telling me to check my drivers, that I am running in software mode.

I have the pacman package containing the nvidia drivers installed and as per the instruction on the arch wiki I have added nvidia modules to mkinitcpio. Unfortunately Cinnamon doesn't detect the drivers provided by the nvidia pacman package.

I have tried all the solutions I can find but to no avail, and am hesitant to use the Nvidia .run file because apparently it's bad practise or something..?

Any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: @roaima Cinnamon  the desktop env, is not detecting the nvidia drivers provided by the nvidia pacman package, on arch linux

Comment: Thank you. I've added that back into your question